# Как понять вторую часть задания? Саму сумму ряда я написал, но так и не понял что от меня требуется в условии) И желательно как это реализовать

Tags: c++

```
#include iostream
#include cmath

int value()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Введите натуральное число n " << std::endl;
        int i;
        std::cin >> i;

        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            std::cout << "Вы ввели неправильное значение. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.\n" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            return i;
        }
    }
}

int value2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Введите целое число a " << std::endl;
        int i;
        std::cin >> i;

        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            std::cout << "Вы ввели неправильное значение. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.\n" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            return i;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    std::cout << "Эта программа считает сумму ряда" << std::endl;
    int a = value2();
    int n = value();
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        ans += pow(2, n-1) * pow(-1, n-1) * a;
    std::cout << "Сумма ряда= " << ans << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Задание]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны ввести число n, а потом **n чисел ai**, а не одно.

Коэффициент при очередном числе проще считать, умножая текущий коэффициент на -2, а не вот эти вот pow использовать.

```
int c = 1;
int a;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
     a = value2();
     ans += c * a;
     с *= -2;
}
```

Ещё можно модифицировать функцию ввода ai, добавив аргумент i и выводя его как подсказку

Comment: Еще и не просто `pow`, а `pow(2, n-1) * pow(-1, n-1)`...

Comment: а вот, например, если ввести n=2, a0 = 2e108, a1 = 2e108, должно посчитать как -2e108, но происходит переполнение. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Откуда такие числа? Они не вмещаются в int, а по условию гарантируется, то переполнения не будет